# Is the use of a word in a morphological gap technically a speech production error?

Tags: morphology, lexical-semantics, production

Typically, speech production errors such as phoneme or morpheme exchange, anticipation, etc. are the result of interference in the speech production process. However, the use of a word in a morphological gap (such as *confusal* or *arrivation*) uses the same speech production process as every other word, and the word is still semantically and morphologically correct, even if it's not present in a language's lexicon. Would this still be classified a speech production error?

Answer (score 1):

I don't thinks this is an interference in the production process. There are rules at play here, as these forms are entirely predictable. Consider the following pairs for now:

```
invite (noun)   -   invitation 

refusal         -   refusation 

describal       -   description 

recital         -   recitation
```

What actually is going on that the various rules are competing during the process of production, and if your lexicon fails you, your morphology helps you out. And the same goes on at the speech community level, hence some speakers may prefer to use a set lexical form: `description`, others may consistently opt for morphological suffixation from the verb: `describal`; while others feel that the most popular -[t/s/x]ion suffix is so universal that they no longer need to remember odd-ball forms, hence `recitation`. Finally, there are those who say, in English if it's good for a verb, it's good for a noun with an initial word-stress, thus we end up with `invite`.

Add a few hundred years, and a few generations of language learners and you get a beautiful, healthy, vibrant grammatical faculty that enables both speech creation and comprehension for most of these word forms.

Stekauer: English Word-formation: A History of Research, 1960-1995 has a nice detailed analysis of there here: https://books.google.hu/books?id=79BV7ZOxI1AC&pg=PA118&lpg=PA118

Examples like `medium / media / mediums / medias` and the like are also highly similar, but cause too much havoc among descriptive and prescriptive linguists.

Comment: For a non-native speaker: Is refusation an acceptable English word, or should it be starred? I only know refutation with a "t" in place of the "s"?

Comment: Your teacher will mark it as incorrect, but language teachers tend to be prescriptive. Linguists will either frown upon it, or will say it is odd, but a natives morphology is at play here. Google has a few hundred hits on it as an English word. For a learner, it is safer to say - do not use it, methinks. It would be hard to win an argument in an exam situation with   it.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I examined some search engine hits and most of them were tables similar to the one you give above.